# Creating hole through mulitple divs

Tags: html, css

Hey guys this question has been asked multiple times but i need to know how to do it through multiple divs.

So i have my HTML set up like this:

```
.body
->.card
-->.nestedcard
--->.nestedinnestedcard
```

With text in all of them.

So now i want my nestedinnested card to "cut a hole" in its backrgound color and also all the backgrounds of the other divs that its infront of.

And ofcourse the hole has to be as big as the nestedinnested div itself is.
I dont want to make the other divs transparent because thats not hole.

```
.card {
  background-color: #778da9;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.nestedcard {
  background-color: #1b263b;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid #CCBBB8;
}

.nestedinnestedcard {
  background-color: #e0e1dd;
  color: #0d1b2a;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid transparent;
}
```

You can find what im refereing to here [and i am refering to the white box that has MVC as a title](https://thijsrietveld.com/index.php?op=mijnwerk)

If you click the link youll see the stary background that i want to be able to see through the div

I hope ive given enough info thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't do that. A hole in one layer sure but not multiple layers.

Comment: There is no way? not even with js?

Comment: @ThijsRietveld so you want `.nestedinnestedcard` to have the same background color as the `<body>`?

Comment: Yes in a way, because i have this background that has moving stars using css. thats not really my body styling its more like a div that is the first thing i load inside the body. but those moving stars i want them to be able to be seen through the nestedinnested div